# Erlang: performance cost for recursive loop

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, erlang

I was programming a simple server in Erlang. Here is my accept loop:

```
loop(Sock) ->
    {ok, Conn} = gen_tcp:accept(Sock),
    Handler = spawn(fun () -> handle(Conn) end),
    gen_tcp:controlling_process(Conn, Handler),
    loop(Sock).
```

This is obviously a recursive function. My question is: how long will my function stack keep increasing if more and more clients connect? Will this affect the performance of my application?

Comment: This isn't a problem in Erlang because of a nifty little gizmo called "[Tail-Call Optimization](http://rhnh.net/2007/12/22/tail-call-optimization-in-erlang)", which eliminates the current stack frame when a function calls itself as its last line, preventing stack smashing and eventual stack overflow.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja *[...] when a function calls itself as its last line [...]* You should be a bit more specific than that.

Comment: True; I should, but I really don't know enough about Erlang or functional programming to describe that in more detail, hence why I left a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erlang handles two kind of recursive functions:

- Recursive Functions
- Tail Recursive Functions

You can learn the difference with sample codes on [this link](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion)

But lets check your code, if you were defined your code like

```
loop(Sock) ->
    {ok, Conn} = gen_tcp:accept(Sock),
    gen_tcp:controlling_process(Conn, Handler), 
    loop(Sock),
    spawn(fun () -> handle(Conn) end).
```

That would be a recursive function and eventually it will overflow the stack because the last line of execution its not calling the `loop` function, but the way you defined your code

```
loop(Sock) ->
    {ok, Conn} = gen_tcp:accept(Sock),
    Handler = spawn(fun () -> handle(Conn) end),
    gen_tcp:controlling_process(Conn, Handler),
    loop(Sock).
```

where the last execution code is calling `loop` function again (it doesn't have to be the last line of code, but it has to be the last function executed, its known as `tail recursion` and it doesn't fill the stack. Erlang uses this mechanism all over the place, its the base of erlang servers.

Regarding the original question of when a recursive function in erlang will stop working, that really depends on the way you are running the beam machine, the code defined on the recursive function, and most probably you should not worry about it because if you code by mistake a recursive function that overflow the stack, it will kill the process, it will be logged, a supervisor will restart the server and eventually you will notice the error and do the fix.